# Oil leak from manifold on 2016 Nissan Micra

Tags: nissan, oil-leak, intake-manifold, micra

My daughter has just bought her first car - a  2016 Nissan micra and it has an oil leak from the manifold. It is under 28 days warranty from trade centre UK. They have booked it in for repair but I am just concerned that there may be underlying problems and I should return it for a refund. It seems strange to me that a 3 year old car with only 22000 miles on the clock would have an oil leak. What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It is hard to say without more information. Can you provide some pictures that detail the location and extent of the leak? If the repair shop is reputable, then they should be able to fix the problem to Nissan standards.